# Enlarging the Length of a Particular Page in the TOC to Accommodate an Additional Entry

Tags: table-of-contents, lengths, page, vertical, addlines

I would like to selectively enlarge the vertical length of a particular page in the TOC to accommodate, say, a "widowed" entry.

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\newcommand*{\redefinesectiontotoc}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{{}#1}{}{}}%
}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip 12pt} %set space after each Chapter in the Table of Contents
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip 8pt}  %set space after each Section in the Table of Contents

% To extend the dots in the Table of Contents over to the Page number
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\bfseries \dotfill}

% To take away the dots from a section display in the Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\hfill}

\begin{document}
Some words.\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter} {\textbf{First Chapter.}}
\redefinesectiontotoc{A Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter} {\textbf{Second Chapter.}}
\redefinesectiontotoc{A Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter} {\textbf{Third Chapter.}}
\redefinesectiontotoc{A Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter} {\textbf{Fourth Chapter.}}
\redefinesectiontotoc{A Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter} {\textbf{First Chapter.}}
\redefinesectiontotoc{\textbf{I would like to be able to enlarge the previous page in the TOC so as to include this entry on it.}}

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

which produces the TOC:

[image]

[image]

QUESTION: How may I make a selective adjustment to the vertical length of a particular page (in this case, to the first page) in order to accommodate an additional entry? Is there a command analogous to, say, `\enlargethispage{1.0\baselineskip}` for a Table of Contents?

Thank you.

Comment: ...just add `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\enlargethispage{<len>}}` somewhere after any chapter that is still on page 1 of the ToC. For example, after **Third Chapter**. I'd suggest changing the vertical skip between entries though, because you'll also have to deal with the page footer location if you enlarge the page.

Comment: Many thanks @Werner for this most helpful comment. It works very nicely. Before posting the question, I had tried something like what you suggest but I couldn't get it to work. I must have either forgotten the `\protect` command or perhaps did not use specifically `\addtocontents`. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\enlargethispage` but there is not room before the footline so her I also used `\thispagestyle{empty} to lose the page number.

[image]

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\newcommand*{\redefinesectiontotoc}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{{}#1}{}{}}%
}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip 12pt} %set space after each Chapter in the Table of Contents
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip 8pt}  %set space after each Section in the Table of Contents

% To extend the dots in the Table of Contents over to the Page number
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\bfseries \dotfill}

% To take away the dots from a section display in the Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\hfill}

\begin{document}
Some words.\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter} {\textbf{First Chapter.}}
\redefinesectiontotoc{A Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter} {\textbf{Second Chapter.}}
\redefinesectiontotoc{A Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter} {\textbf{Third Chapter.}}
\redefinesectiontotoc{A Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter} {\textbf{Fourth Chapter.}}
\redefinesectiontotoc{A Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter---Another Topic from the Chapter}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter} {\textbf{First Chapter.}}
\redefinesectiontotoc{\textbf{I would like to be able to enlarge the previous page in the TOC so as to include this entry on it.}}

\newpage
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\enlargethispage{4\baselineskip}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

In practice I think I'd avoid extending the page and instead shrink the vertical spaces a bit (or do both).

Comment: Many thanks @David Carlisle.

Comment: A question on your code if I may: Doesn't the command `\enlargethispage{4\baselineskip}` enlarge the current page by `4\baselineskip` as well?

Comment: it just enlarges the current page, you had already added `\newpage` so it's already on the first page of the toc by then (you could add it via `\addtocontents` as I did `\thispagestyle` that one I had to do after the heading inserted but \tableofcontents to over-ride the plain page style it was setting, @mlchristians