# memoir.sty: enlarge toc page

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

Dear TeXperts:  I want to add some space to one of my toc pages.  Unfortunately

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\enlargethispage{1\baselineskip}}$
```

adds an empty chapter page number.  (Same on section.  With `\maxtocdepth` of section, I can't go lower, either.)  What is the right way to increase my toc page?

Comment: There's also `\addtocontents` that doesn't reference a page number.

Comment: that's the answer: `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\enlargethispage{1\baselineskip}`.

Comment: Potential duplicate: [Enlarging the Length of a Particular Page in the TOC to Accommodate an Additional Entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/633952)